# .gitignore for svg-inkscape

Tags: svg, inkscape, git

I managed to get SVG to work with LuaTeX. However, in my working folder, there's a new folder named `svg-inkscape`. Is this a mandatory folder? Can I ignore it, and if so, is there a proper `.gitignore` file for all these svg related stuff? I'm currently using the [github's `TEX.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/TeX.gitignore), but it doesn't help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX can't directly include SVG files. Because of this, the `svg` package calls Inkscape which converts your `.svg` drawing into a `.pdf` and a `.pdf_tex` file. When you say `\includesvg{drawing}` in your document, the package (checks if these files have to be (re)created and then) just inputs `drawing.pdf_tex`, which contains the TeX commands necessary to include the pages of `drawing.pdf` (they act as layers) and place the text contained in the drawing on top of that.

So, for every SVG drawing you include, two temporary files are created. Not deleting them after compilation speeds up the next one, as they don't have to be created anew. In order not to clutter the directory where you load your `.svg` files from, the `svg` package courteously creates the folder `svg-inkscape` and puts all of them there. You can safely delete it, it will be recreated and repopulated upon compilation.

So, to answer your question: Yes, you can ignore this folder. For Git, just add

```
# svg
svg-inkscape/
```

to your `.gitignore` file.